# Making Mongodb documents inactive after certain time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I am creating a web application that posts event markers to a map to help flash mobs find out where to meet up. In this hypothetical app and due to the nature of flash mobs, these markers would have to become inactive after a certain time interval so as to not pollute the map with events that are no longer occurring. My question is what is the appropriate way to allow this to happen in mongoDB using node.js without deleting the document?

If I have a mongoose model (Marker) like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const markerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
    select: false,
  },
  expiresAt: {
    type: Date
  },
  active: Boolean,
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String, 
      enum: ['Point'], 
      required: true,
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true,
    },
  },
});

markerSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.expiresAt = this.createdAt + 60 * 60 * 1000 * 6;
  next();
});

const Marker = mongoose.model('Marker', tourSchema);

module.exports = Marker;
```

What would be the best way to update the markers active field to false after an arbitrary amount of time, say 6 hours?

I have researched Mongodb's TTL and I have also considered using the createdAt field to query for markers that are within the time frame of active using Marker.find({ expiresAt: {$gt: Date.now() }) but I do not know if this would be the best. Is there a way to run a function or middleware that periodically checks each document and sets the active field to false if the time frame is up? Just curious how you would approach this problem so querying Marker.find({ active: true }) would provide the data I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Setting TTL in MongoDB runs a scheduled task every 60 seconds and will remove the document once expired. If you don't want to remove the document and mark it instead.

1. Run a CRON/Scheduled task every minute
2. Update the document matching your custom TTL criteria
3. Use the criteria in all select clause to ignore expired documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `node-cron` to achieve your goal.

For example, rub a job every minute :

```js
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function() {
    console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

More details and full usage example tutorials :

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples
- https://blog.logrocket.com/task-scheduling-or-cron-jobs-in-node-using-node-cron/